# How render in html a many levels mysql query(codeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

this is the mysql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS up
JOIN users AS u ON up.id = u.parent_id
JOIN users AS uc ON u.id = uc.parent_id
WHERE up.id =16
```

and this is the output in the view file

```
   <?php foreach($query->result() as $q): ?>
    <?php echo $q->id; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the mysql result gives 3 levels of result, but in html it outputs only 1 level, and is the last level, but i need to render it in a hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```sql
SELECT up.id AS id1, u.id AS id2, uc.id AS id3
FROM users AS up
JOIN users AS u  ON up.id =  u.parent_id
JOIN users AS uc ON  u.id = uc.parent_id
WHERE up.id = 16
```

Then you can access the three levels as `id1`, `id2` and `id3`:

```
<?php
  foreach($query->result() as $q) {
    echo $q->id1;
    echo $q->id2;
    echo $q->id3;
  }
?>
```